# Find PDFs that start with same 5 characters and combine them

Tags: pdf, applescript, automator

need help creating a workflow to combine PDFs. I work for a printing company and we send PDF proofs. Export PDF from say InDesign to a specific folder. Then watermark the PDFs, then combine the different items into a single PDF, add a sign off page then encrypt.

I have the Folder action already created to watermark the PDFs as they hit the folder and save to a different folder (Applescript calling the Acrobat JavaScript). I am not sure how to script finding files that start with the same 5 characters. Our files look like this:

12345 BC.pdf
12345 LH.pdf
12345 #10.pdf

For the various items. 12345 being the 5 digit job number. I need to find however many items start with the same job number, then combine them into a single file so that I can then add the sign off sheet, then encrypt and save as the job number.

Have been working in Automator and some Applescript, but new to all of this. I currently export PDFs, run an Acrobat watermark action, then manually combine the PDFs, then run another Acrobat action to insert the sign off page and encrypt. Trying to automate the whole process.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: What do you have so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Look into pdftk.

Comment: Or pdfrw.  It will do the watermarking and combining, but knows nothing about the encryption.  (Disclaimer:  I am the pdfrw author.)

Comment: http://macosautomation.com/automator/combinePDFs/index.html  https://pastebin.com/xvhkZMU3

Comment: Thanks guys for the replies.

@Chilly so far I just have the folder action to Watermark and save to a new folder. I am stuck at trying to combine the files automatically by job number (first 5 digits). 

Sethmr and Patrick Maupin, I will look into those. Trying to do this without any extra input needed. Export PDF and the automation takes over.

Comment: If we made sure to only export one job at a time, I could just have it select all the files that are in the Watermarked folder, but how could I extract the job number so that it would save it by itself without having to ask what to name it? Sorry for all the questions, trying to learn this as I go. I've got about 15 tabs open that I am bouncing around in. Thanks again guys!

Comment: I found this:

on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Finder" to return name of (item 1 of input) 
end run

And then Save that as a variable. Which is working to save as the first item in the folder, but it ends up being 12345 BC.pdf.pdf. Is it possible to only return the first 5 characters? I have tried return text 1 thru 5 instead of name but that doesn't work. Looks like that is only for strings?

Comment: So new to this...

`on run {input, parameters}
tell application "Finder" to return name of (item 1 of input)
end run`

Comment: Found something that works so far. I save the full name of the file as one variable fileName then Run Shell Script cut -c1-5 ${fileName} and save that as variable jobNumber and use that to rename the combined PDF. Now to sort out why I the watermark action is looping through more than once.